# Google Maps Android API v2 - API key de Debug não está funcionando

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Estou tentando usar a *Google Maps Android API v2* em meu aplicativo Android. Ela estava funcionando no micro de um outro desenvolvedor, com a `debug.keystore` dele, porém com a minha `debug.keystore` (localizada em `C:\Users\Meu Usuário\.android\debug.keystore`) não está funcionando.

A *Google Maps Android API v2* está habilitada e eu já criei uma *API Key* seguindo os passos normais:

1. Rodar o comando `keytool -list -v -keystore debug.keystore` para obter a string SHA1;
2. Usar a string SHA1 para criar uma *API key* no *Google Developers Console* seguindo o formato `stringSHA1;br.com.meuapp`;
3. Incluir a *API key* em meu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

   ```
   <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="8"
       android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

   <permission
       android:name="br.com.meuapp.MAPS_RECEIVE"
       android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="br.com.meuapp.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

   <uses-feature
           android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
           android:required="true"/>

   <application
       ...

       <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

       <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

       ...

       <!-- Debug API key -->
       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
           android:value="AIzaSy*********************************"/>

   </application>
   ```

Porém, nada está resolvendo (o mapa não aparece) e o LogCat sempre mostra o erro abaixo:

```
06-02 17:25:51.601: E/Google Maps Android API(5354): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

A conectividade do dispositivo está OK.

Já chequei e re-chequei a geração da *API key*, o valor da string SHA1, etc.

A fim de permitir compatibilidade com versões de Android inferiores à 3.0 estou usando as APIs de compatibilidade (`SupportMapFragment`, etc).

A versão da minha biblioteca *Google Play Services* é `4323000`.

Estou usando o Eclipse.

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estranhamente, liguei o computador e o dispositivo de testes hoje e o mapa funcionou. Acredito que faltava esta reinicialização ou então dar tempo para a *API Key* ser aceita pelos servidores do Google. De qualquer forma o problema está resolvido. Agradeço aos que se dispuseram a ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Penso que sei o que se passa com o teu mapa.

Existem duas strings SHA1 que são geradas, uma para o apk e outra para usar quando a app arranca com o IDE.

A que tu deves precisar registar no google é a do IDE que podes encontrar no ADT em Window -> Preferences ->Android ->  Build.

Comment: Na verdade as duas vêm do mesmo keystore, que está localizado no caminho que eu citei, portanto têm o mesmo valor de SHA1.